Hourly refresh limit error for decision table
This error limit occurred when deploying new decision tables into another sandbox :
"We couldn’t refresh the decision table because you reached the org limit of 20 refreshes per hour. Try again later"

Context: our deployment package contained 7 decision tables and some other metadata (fields, action button, ...)
This error started to appear after 3rd deployment retry while fixing deployment errors related to other components in the package.
The 3 deployment retries occurred during the same hour and since there are 7 decision tables in the package (total refresh = 21), hence exceeding the 20 limit.
Basically, we had to wait before retrying the deployment.
Currently, the documentation does not mention anything about this limit :
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.reference_decision_table_data_limits.htm&type=5
Snapshot of limits documentation :


Update 2024-08-02 :
Salesforce support increased the limit to 40 refreshes per hour, this is the maximum they can do for now.
Test done in sandbox using a screen flow with 7 action elements each executing a refresh on a specific decision table and it seems that refresh is possible after 3 retries (difficult to accurately calculate this since refreshes are queued).
Note that even if limit is increased in the org, Salesforce still indicate 20 in the error message "We couldn’t refresh the decision table because you reached the org limit of 20 refreshes per hour. Try again later." and as per response below from support, the error message is currently hardcoded and will be updated in next release.

Case #467905870 :
We have received a confirmation from the engineering team that this is a message issue.
The error message is hard-coded to the text and they have informed that they will be fixing it in next release.
Unfortunately, There is no way to see the currently reached limit.

Update 2024-07-29:
Contacted Salesforce support who confirmed that this limit is unfortunately not documented yet and will be updated accordingly.
After analysis, engineering team said that as of now, they can increase the limit to 40 refresh per hour.
It is still unknown if this limit can be further increased in the future.
Hope this helps if anyone else encounters this issue
